# Can't Create directory with 'FtpCreateDirectory'

Tags: ms-access, ftp, vba

here is wininet.dll declare functions:

```
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" _
                        (ByVal sAgent As String, _
                         ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
                         ByVal sProxyName As String, _
                         ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
                         ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" _
                        (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
                         ByVal sServerName As String, _
                         ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
                         ByVal sUsername As String, _
                         ByVal sPassword As String, _
                         ByVal lService As Long, _
                         ByVal lFlags As Long, _
                         ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub FtpCreateDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" _
                         Alias "FtpCreateDirectoryA" _
                        (ByVal hConnect As Long, _
                         ByVal lpszDirectory As String)

Private Declare Function FtpSetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA" _
                        (ByVal hConnect As Long, _
                         ByVal lpszDirectory As String) As Boolean
```

this is my code:

```
If FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConnect, sDir) = False Then
    j = CountOccurrences(sDir, "/")
    Debug.Print "dir = " & sDir
    Debug.Print "j = " & j
    For i = 1 To j
        If i = 1 Then
            intOccChar = InStr(1, sDir, "/")
        Else
            intOccChar = InStr(intOccChar + 1, sDir, "/")
        End If
        Debug.Print "for i=" & i & " intOccChar = " & intOccChar
        Debug.Print Left(sDir, intOccChar)
        Debug.Print FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConnect, Left(sDir,(intOccChar)))
        If FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConnect, Left(sDir, (intOccChar))) = False Then 
            Call FtpCreateDirectory(hConnect, Left(sDir, (intOccChar)))  

        End If

    Next
End If

Call FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConnect, sDir)
```

**problem is:** when there is no directory on ftp server, code works well but when first directory exist then sub directory not created

This is Immediate windows output:

```
dir = AkhzaBank/80/2/Credit/
j = 4
for i=1 intOccChar = 10
AkhzaBank/
False
for i=2 intOccChar = 13
AkhzaBank/80/
False
for i=3 intOccChar = 15
AkhzaBank/80/2/
False
for i=4 intOccChar = 22
AkhzaBank/80/2/Credit/
False
```

note: the code works with ftp upload and download, the only problem is create directory on ftp server

Thanks in advance

Comment: declare functions added.

Comment: Good. I think the input might not get recognized as a fully qualified path. Try passing only the directory name of the directory you want to create, not the full path, to create it in the current working directory. You can use `Err.LastDLLError` to get an error code, and look that up, or [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/formatmessage.aspx) has helper functions for API errors.

Comment: Check ACL of former created dir. Maybe ftp-user is not allowed to create dirs there, because it was created by a different user.

Answer (score 1):

update!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

<del>I find a solution form my question</del>

<del>i don't know why, but somehow this line</del>

<del>If FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hConnect, Left(sDir, (intOccChar))) = False Then</del>

<del>prevents create directory in subfolder. i simply delete this line and code works.</del>

true solution
  My mistake is in these lines:

```
Private Declare Sub FtpCreateDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" _
                         Alias "FtpCreateDirectoryA" _
                        (ByVal hConnect As Long, _
                         ByVal lpszDirectory As String)
```

i must Declare FtpCreateDirectory as Boolean Function not as Sub! so the true declare function is:

```
Private Declare Function FtpCreateDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" _
                         Alias "FtpCreateDirectoryA" _
                        (ByVal hConnect As Long, _
                         ByVal lpszDirectory As String) As Boolean
```